# Getting coordinates of user's location (OneShotLocationManager)

Tags: ios, swift, location

I am currently trying to make a weather app. It is using the http://developer.forecast.io API, which accepts longitude and latitude coordinates to find the weather. I have OneShotLocationManager implemented, but I can't quite get the coordinates from it then use them with the Forecast API.

Here's my code:

```
var manager: OneShotLocationManager?
let coordinate: (lat: Double, long: Double) = (0,0)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    manager = OneShotLocationManager()
    manager!.fetchWithCompletion { location, error in

        // fetch location or an error
        if let loc = location {
            print(location?.coordinate.latitude)
            print(location?.coordinate.longitude)
            let coordinate: (lat: Double, long: Double) = ((location?.coordinate.latitude)!,location!.coordinate.longitude)
        } else if let err = error {
            print(err.localizedDescription)
        }

        self.manager = nil

    } }
```

I can get OneShotLocationManager to print the coordinates to the console, but I can't figure out how to actually use them with Forecast.io. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: ok, you have your coordinates, now you must do a request for the data to the API. I don't see that code here.

Comment: @HugoAlonso That's not the issue. I have that figured out. It takes the coordinates from the "coordinate" variable. I need to figure out how to store the user's coordinates in the "coordinate" variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no need to use location var anymore, for that reason you do the **`if let`** check.
Try this:

```
if let loc = location {
   let coordinate = (lat: loc.coordinate.latitude, long: loc.coordinate.longitude)
   // ...your web API request stuff using coordinate....
}
```